# Fill php array with msql fetch

Tags: php, arrays, loops, indexing, fetch

I would like to get the "till.code" values and save them with an incremental numeric index array . 
The idea is that I could print those values with "$array[$variable],$array[$variable]..etc". Variable should be a numeric number,1,2,3..

```
 $stmt2=$dbh->prepare("SELECT till.code,shop.description Collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI as description, count(tra.id) as servicios,ROUND(sum(tra.total_amount),1) as facturacion
          FROM [TCPOS4].[dbo].[transactions] as tra, [TCPOS4].[dbo].[tills] as till,[TCPOS4].[dbo].[shops] as shop where tra.till_id=till.id and shop.id=till.shop_id  and convert(date,tra.trans_date) = '$name2' and '$usuari'=CAST(LEFT(shop.code,5) AS INT) group by till.code,shop.description order by code;");

    $stmt2->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
         **I have to fill this.**
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way, which may not be the best way, but that depends on the scenario would be:

```
$index = 1;
$arr = array();
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
     $arr[ $index ] = $row;
     $index++;
}
```

Comment: How can I print the second value from the array? echo $arr[2]  ?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the second row. If you want the second value within a row you will have to use `$arr[2]['name of the value']`. You can access `$arr` like you do any other array.

Comment: What is the name of the value? Is not possible to print the array with an index as a variable? I am not able to print my values with echo $arr[$index]

Comment: use `print_r($arr[$index])`, or show the code where you are trying to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood but perhaps something like this. Assign an alias to the column to make things easier.

```
$stmt2=$dbh->prepare("SELECT 
                        till.code as 'code',
                        shop.description Collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AI as 'description', 
                        count(tra.id) as 'servicios',
                        ROUND(sum(tra.total_amount),1) as 'facturacion'
                    FROM
                        [TCPOS4].[dbo].[transactions] as tra, 
                        [TCPOS4].[dbo].[tills] as till,
                        [TCPOS4].[dbo].[shops] as shop 
                    WHERE tra.till_id=till.id
                            and shop.id=till.shop_id 
                            and convert(date,tra.trans_date) = '$name2' 
                            and '$usuari'=CAST(LEFT(shop.code,5) AS INT) 
                    GROUP BY till.code,shop.description
                    ORDER BY code;");

    $stmt2->execute();
    $output=array();
    while( $row = $stmt2->fetch() )$output[]=$row->code;
```